# How to change the way vim displays hard tabs

Tags: vim

How would you make vim display tabs as 4 spaces?
I tried playing with `set list` and `set listchars` But this only changes the 8 characters representing the the tab. I want to keep the tabs, but have them take 4 spaces instead of 8. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:h 'ts'
```

you will see:

```
'tabstop' 'ts'      number  (default 8)
            local to buffer
    Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for.  Also see
    |:retab| command, and 'softtabstop' option.

    Note: Setting 'tabstop' to any other value than 8 can make your file
    appear wrong in many places (e.g., when printing it).

    There are four main ways to use tabs in Vim:
    1. Always keep 'tabstop' at 8, set 'softtabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to 4
       (or 3 or whatever you prefer) and use 'noexpandtab'.  Then Vim
       will use a mix of tabs and spaces, but typing <Tab> and <BS> will
       behave like a tab appears every 4 (or 3) characters.
    2. Set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to whatever you prefer and use
       'expandtab'.  This way you will always insert spaces.  The
       formatting will never be messed up when 'tabstop' is changed.
    3. Set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to whatever you prefer and use a
       |modeline| to set these values when editing the file again.  Only
       works when using Vim to edit the file.
    4. Always set 'tabstop' and 'shiftwidth' to the same value, and
       'noexpandtab'.  This should then work (for initial indents only)
       for any tabstop setting that people use.  It might be nice to have
       tabs after the first non-blank inserted as spaces if you do this
       though.  Otherwise aligned comments will be wrong when 'tabstop' is


   changed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The width of a Tab character is determined by the `'tabstop'` option:

```
:set tabstop=4
```

Note that changing this from the default of 8 may affect how other programs display the file, and is therefore discouraged. In such a case, better insert literal space characters (via `:set expandtab`).